# In-App Billing Expiration

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

**In-App Billing / In-App Purchase**

I'm developing an app for both Android and iOS.

I noticed that both have **In-App Billing** service.

I'm worried about the expiration dates of the *extras* people can buy in-app.

I know you can bill for an extra monthly and yearly, but let's say I want the user to buy an extra and the expiration date is 1 day. Is it possible?

Which are the allowed expiration dates?

Another question (haven't digged much yet) is about iOS **In-App-Purchase**, is it like Android's one? What are the main differences (if any)?

And yet another question, are there any fees that Google and Apple apply on the extras?
**Edit:** I found out that there exists 30% fees for both of them, meh...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a lot of questions I'll try to answer all of them.

The way to set up an expiration date of 1 day is to manage the user entitlement on your end. This means that you can pretty much do whatever you want and you simply use Google/Apple for billing. In Google - you should look for "unmanaged" products. In Apple "consumable" would give you the most flexibility. Going in that route is slightly more complicated as you need to set up a way to track what the user purchased and when does it expire.

There are a few differences between Apple and Android in-app purchase. Generally, Google are a bit more flexible and Apple give you slightly better tools. Unmanaged product in Android is the same as consumable in Apple and Managed is the equivalent of non-consumable.

Regarding the fees - 30% is their cut indeed. The only situation in which the fee is avoided is if you sell vouchers somewhere else (online or offline) and the user brings a voucher code to the app. This is true as long as the app doesn't refer users (i.e. link) to the site selling vouchers.

Comment: I already came across that SOOMLA Project of yours earlier and found it really helpful! Thanks for your great answer as it surely answers all of my questions. Thanks for the invitation for an early access but at the moment I don't need it, as I'm working on another project right now and later I'll get onto it. Once again, thanks!